# On the continuity of a Set-Valued function (correspondence)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, set-valued-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a set-valued function defined by
\begin{equation*}
f\left( x\right) =\left\{ y\in \mathbb{R}^{m}:g\left( x\right) +h\left(
    x\right) ^{T}y\leq 0\right\} \text{,}
    \end{equation*}
where $g:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $h:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow 
    \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are continuous functions. How do you show that $f$ is
continuous in $\mathbb{R}^{n}\diagdown\left\{  0\right\}  $?

Answer (score 6):

You don't, in general. In the special case,
$$f\left( x\right) =\left\{ y\in \mathbb{R}^{m}:
    x ^{T}y\leq 0\right\} \text{,}$$
you get an obvious lack of lower hemicontinuity at $0$.